# Reading and writing a floating point value to a NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, .net, numericupdown

In C# I have a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control that represents a floating point value, for example 2.3. It can be incremented and decremented by 0.1 from the user interface.

However, this value can not be written or read programmatically, because it is an int in C#. I need to be able to read and write this float (or double) value.

Currently the compiler is forcing me to cast it into an int and dropping the decimal places. This is a bug in C# obviously.

Comment: Please show the code where you think VS is forcing you to cast to an int.

Comment: Obviously _not_ a bug in C#, which is only the programming language! C# has nothing to do with the control, which may (but probably does not) have a bug.

Answer (score 8):

In case you are having problem with showing decimal values, then set the **DecimalPlaces** property to 2 or more.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, [last time I checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value.aspx) the `NumericUpDown.Value` property was a decimal...

```
decimal d = NumericUpDown.Value;
```

Comment: [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value.aspx) it's a decimal...

Answer (score 2):

I use it like this, and it worked for me.

to set a double value into numericUpDown control,

```
numericUpDown1.Value = new decimal((double)InputVal);
```

and you can obtain the value from `numericUpDown1` like below:

```
double val = (double)numericUpDown1.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option to using the decimal type is to put a textbox directly over the text portion of the NumericUpDown control without covering the updown buttons.

I used the events raised by the NumericUpDown control, but used the textbox in front of the numeric updown display to retrieve and post the results of the events.

I would recommend creating a new class that inherits the numericUpDown class and add the functionality you want there by adding methods with new names or by overriding methods of the NumericUpDown class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
double Dimension1Data = Convert.ToDouble(Dimension1.Value);
```

where `Dimension1` is the `NumericUpDown` control.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. My numericUpDown'Increment' value is set to 0,5. By Form_Load I needed the numericUpDown.Value to be 5,5. all I made is this:

```
numericUpDown1.Value = 5;
numericUpDown1.UpButton();
```

..or `numericUpDown1.Value = (decimal)5.5;`